# Azure data factory - cost of inactive pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-billing, azure-cost-calculation

Is there any additional cost for adf 2 inactive pipelines?
I've found the information that there is a cost in adf1 but what about adf2?
I need Microsoft official documentation if there is a cost.

Comment: In the FAQ listed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/ you can find also the question for inactive pipelines for v2 ADF (load more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cost involved for Inactive pipeline in ADF v2 unlike ADF v1.
n ADF v2, you only pay for data pipeline orchestration by activity run and activity execution by integration runtime hours (For IR charges are prorated by the minute and rounded up)

Email thread:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1015698/cost-factors-for-azure-data-factory.html